# How can i get a definitive answer from my manager for my perm contract?

Tags: human-resources, manager, promotion, contractors

I've been working for my current company since April last year. I currently work in an administrative role. I am a contractor with an ongoing contract. After 2 months of me working here, my manager left and my new line manager is currently working part time so I ended up doing a lot more of what I was hired for. I've been approached before by my new manager saying they are "fighting" to making me perm but this is a conversation that keeps going on since the summer, and at this point, I don't buy it anymore. I really like the company so i would like to find a way to speak clearly to my manager to get some real answers. Any suggestions?

Comment: What "real answers" do you need? Your new manager clearly hasn't won the fight and there is no sign from either Heaven or Hell that this fight is going to be won any time soon or in the foreseeable future.

Comment: "Hey Manager, do you have a minute? I have a question and I need a definite answer by $date". Prepare to get "no" as a definite answer.

Comment: A nail gun, definitely.  Nail his feet to the floor until he either bleeds out or gives you a response.  (smile) Actually, there's nothing you can do.  What you CAN do is (a) figure out what you're missing by not being a perm employee and (b) either bridge the gap out-of-pocket or find a new job and (c) exercise some gratitude in the meantime.  You can't force anyone to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a definitive answer from your new line manager regarding when/if you will be made permanent, then you need to ask for it.

If they can't or won't provide an answer to your satisfaction, you can:

1. accept this until something changes that will affect their answer
2. threaten to leave unless they make you permanent
3. find a new job for yourself

I would recommend option 1 based on what you've said (especially if you enjoy working there and would rather not have to find another job, even if it means continuing to be on short term contract) and would highly suspect that taking option 2 would lead to you being forced to take option 3 anyway.

It seems that simple to me at least, I don't think you're likely to get any answers which give you a magic solution to the fact that your line manager isn't able/willing to make you permanent at the moment.